# Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout"

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx

I am developing a library for Android, and this library has some activities with its layouts.

In the layout, I have the next code

```
...
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
...
```

I am using Androidx.

An I get the following error:

> Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

The first attempt to solve this was to change`android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

But when I do this I get the following error:

> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group

So I try to change to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group`

I get the following error:

> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group cannot be cast to
>   android.view.ViewGroup

I did a refactor again to androidx and then I get the following error:

> Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout"

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: check -> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' this dependency added in your app level build.gradle or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow this steps

> First add below `dependencies` in your `Build.Gradle` file

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

> Use this `ConstraintLayout` like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Make sure you have correct imports of `ConstraintLayout` for in your activity if you have used

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```